# Fatal error: Class 'JLog' not found in

Tags: php, joomla

I'm storing my Joomla site in localhost (xampp server). When I go the site URL, the page shows the following error message:

```
******Fatal error: Class 'JLog' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\kwazulu\libraries\joomla\error\error.php on line 35**2****
```

Please help me fix this problem

thanks,
mohan

Comment: What version of Joomla and PHP are you using? Have you been editing any core files?

Answer (score 0):

add this in your model file...

```
jimport( 'joomla.error.log' );
```

Hope this will helps you.....

Answer (score 0):

I found my libraries/joomla/log/ folder empty so i re-downloaded corresponding joomla version package and coppied original libraries/joomla/log/ files from package to my joomla libraries/joomla/log/ directory. Error disappeared.